# How to "Show Slicing" in Xcode 13?

Tags: xcode

In XCode 12 it is in the right bottom corner.
Now it is absent =(

PS
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 8):

- List item
- Open xcassets
- Select an image
- In the right top corner press "..."
- Press "Show Slicing"

[image]

Comment: A more discoverable interface: Choose Editor > Show Slicing.